# Make a dictionary from two functions (Python)

Tags: python, dictionary

I need to make a dictionary from two functions (ZoekAccesieCode + ZoekOrganisme). The function ZoekAccesieCode returns lines like "Q6GZX2" and ZoekOrganisme like "Frog virus 3 (isolate Goorha)". ZoekAccesieCode need to be the key and ZoekOrganisme need to be the value. Here is my code:

```
import re
file = open("ploop.txt")
text = file.read()
file.close()

def main():
    hits = VindHits()
    accesie = ZoekAccesieCode(hits)
    organisme = ZoekOrganisme(hits, accesie)
    MaakDict(accesie, organisme)

def VindHits():
    eiwitten = text.split("\n\n")[1:]
    eiwitHits = []

    for eiwit in eiwitten:
        if re.search(r"[AG].{4}GK[ST]", eiwit):
            eiwitHits.append(eiwit)
    return(eiwitHits)

def ZoekAccesieCode(hits):
    for eiwit in hits:
        accesieCode = re.findall(r">sp\|(.{6})", eiwit)[0]
    return accesieCode

def ZoekOrganisme(hits, accesie):
    for eiwit in hits:
        organisme = re.findall(r"\n.+?\[(.+?)\]", eiwit)[0]
    return organisme


def MaakDict(accesie, organisme):

main()
```

Some sample data from the file:

```
    Hits for PS00017|ATP_GTP_A (pattern) ATP/GTP-binding site motif A (P-loop) :  [occurs frequently]
   Pattern: [AG]-x(4)-G-K-[ST]
   Approximate number of expected random matches in ~ 100'000 sequences (50'000'000 residues): 3371


>sp|Q6GZX2|003R_FRG3G  (438 aa)
Uncharacterized protein 3R.  [Frog virus 3 (isolate Goorha) (FV-3)]
MARPLLGKTSSVRRRLESLSACSIFFFLRKFCQKMASLVFLNSPVYQMSNILLTERRQVDRAMGGSDDDGVMVVALSPSD
FKTVLGSALLAVERDMVHVVPKYLQTPGILHDMLVLLTPIFGEALSVDMSGATDVMVQQIATAGFVDVDPLHSSVSWKDN
VSCPVALLAVSNAVRTMMGQPCQVTLIIDVGTQNILRDLVNLPVEMSGDLQVMAYTKDPLGKVPAVGVSVFDSGSVQKGD
AHSVGAPDGLVSFHTHPVSSAVELNYHAGWPSNVDMSSLLTMKNLMHVVVAEEGLWTMARTLSMQRLTKVLTDAEKDVMR
AAAFNLFLPLNELRVMGTKDSNNKSLKTYFEVFETFTIGALMKHSGVTPTAFVDRRWLDNTIYHMGFIPWGRDMRFVVEY
DLDGTNPFLNTVPTLMSVKRKAKIQEMFDNMVSRMVTS
      2 - 9:          ArpllGKT


>sp|Q6GZX1|004R_FRG3G  (60 aa)
Uncharacterized protein 004R.  [Frog virus 3 (isolate Goorha) (FV-3)]
MNAKYDTDQGVGRMLFLGTIGLAVVVGGLMAYGYYYDGKTPSSGTSFHTASPSFSSRYRY
      33 - 40:        GyyydGKT


>sp|Q6GZW0|015R_FRG3G  (322 aa)
Uncharacterized protein 015R.  [Frog virus 3 (isolate Goorha) (FV-3)]
MEQVPIKEMRLSDLRPNNKSIDTDLGGTKLVVIGKPGSGKSTLIKALLDSKRHIIPCAVVISGSEEANGFYKGVVPDLFI
YHQFSPSIIDRIHRRQVKAKAEMGSKKSWLLVVIDDCMDNAKMFNDKEVRALFKNGRHWNVLVVIANQYVMDLTPDLRSS
VDGVFLFRENNVTYRDKTYANFASVVPKKLYPTVMETVCQNYRCMFIDNTKATDNWHDSVFWYKAPYSKSAVAPFGARSY
WKYACSKTGEEMPAVFDNVKILGDLLLKELPEAGEALVTYGGKDGPSDNEDGPSDDEDGPSDDEEGLSKDGVSEYYQSDL
DD
      34 - 41:        GkpgsGKS


>sp|P32234|128UP_DROME  (368 aa)
GTP-binding protein 128up.  [Drosophila melanogaster (Fruit fly)]
MSTILEKISAIESEMARTQKNKATSAHLGLLKAKLAKLRRELISPKGGGGGTGEAGFEVAKTGDARVGFVGFPSVGKSTL
LSNLAGVYSEVAAYEFTTLTTVPGCIKYKGAKIQLLDLPGIIEGAKDGKGRGRQVIAVARTCNLIFMVLDCLKPLGHKKL
LEHELEGFGIRLNKKPPNIYYKRKDKGGINLNSMVPQSELDTDLVKTILSEYKIHNADITLRYDATSDDLIDVIEGNRIY
IPCIYLLNKIDQISIEELDVIYKIPHCVPISAHHHWNFDDLLELMWEYLRLQRIYTKPKGQLPDYNSPVVLHNERTSIED
FCNKLHRSIAKEFKYALVWGSSVKHQPQKVGIEHVLNDEDVVQIVKKV
      71 - 78:        GfpsvGKS


>sp|P05080|194K_TRVSY  (1707 aa)
Replicase large subunit.  [Tobacco rattle virus (strain SYM)]
MANGNFKLSQLLNVDEMSAEQRSHFFDLMLTKPDCEIGQMMQRVVVDKVDDMIRERKTKDPVIVHEVLSQKEQNKLMEIY
PEFNIVFKDDKNMVHGFAAAERKLQALLLLDRVPALQEVDDIGGQWSFWVTRGEKRIHSCCPNLDIRDDQREISRQIFLT
AIGDQARSGKRQMSENELWMYDQFRKNIAAPNAVRCNNTYQGCTCRGFSDGKKKGAQYAIALHSLYDFKLKDLMATMVEK
KTKVVHAAMLFAPESMLVDEGPLPSVDGYYMKKNGKIYFGFEKDPSFSYIHDWEEYKKYLLGKPVSYQGNVFYFEPWQVR
GDTMLFSIYRIAGVPRRSLSSQEYYRRIYISRWENMVVVPIFDLVESTRELVKKDLFVEKQFMDKCLDYIARLSDQQLTI
SNVKSYLSSNNWVLFINGAAVKNKQSVDSRDLQLLAQTLLVKEQVARPVMRELREAILTETKPITSLTDVLGLISRKLWK
QFANKIAVGGFVGMVGTLIGFYPKKVLTWAKDTPNGPELCYENSHKTKVIVFLSVVYAIGGITLMRRDIRDGLVKKLCDM
FDIKRGAHVLDVENPCRYYEINDFFSSLYSASESGETVLPDLSEVKAKSDKLLQQKKEIADEFLSAKFSNYSGSSVRTSP
PSVVGSSRSGLGLLLEDSNVLTQARVGVSRKVDDEEIMEQFLSGLIDTEAEIDEVVSAFSAECERGETSGTKVLCKPLTP
PGFENVLPAVKPLVSKGKTVKRVDYFQVMGGERLPKRPVVSGDNSVDARREFLYYLDAERVAQNDEIMSLYRDYSRGVIR
TGGQNYPHGLGVWDVEMKNWCIRPVVTEHAYVFQPDKRMDDWSGYLEVAVWERGMLVNDFAVERMSDYVIVCDQTYLCNN
RLILDNLSALDLGPVNCSFELVDGVPGCGKSTMIVNSANPCVDVVLSTGRAATDDLIERFASKGFPCKLKRRVKTVDSFL
MHCVDGSLTGDVLHFDEALMAHAGMVYFCAQIAGAKRCICQGDQNQISFKPRVSQVDLRFSSLVGKFDIVTEKRETYRSP
ADVAAVLNKYYTGDVRTHNATANSMTVRKIVSKEQVSLKPGAQYITFLQSEKKELVNLLALRKVAAKVSTVHESQGETFK
DVVLVRTKPTDDSIARGREYLIVALSRHTQSLVYETVKEDDVSKEIRESAALTKAALARFFVTETVLXRFRSRFDVFRHH
EGPCAVPDSGTITDLEMWYDALFPGNSLRDSSLDGYLVATTDCNLRLDNVTIKSGNWKDKFAEKETFLKPVIRTAMPDKR
KTTQLESLLALQKRNQAAPDLQENVHATVLIEETMKKLKSVVYDVGKIRADPIVNRAQMERWWRNQSTAVQAKVVADVRE
LHEIDYSSYMYMIKSDVKPKTDLTPQFEYSALQTVVYHEKLINSLFGPIFKEINERKLDAMQPHFVFNTRMTSSDLNDRV
KFLNTEAAYDFVEIDMSKFDKSANRFHLQLQLEIYRLFGLDEWAAFLWEVSHTQTTVRDIQNGMMAHIWYQQKSGDADTY
NANSDRTLCALLSELPLEKAVMVTYGGDDSLIAFPRGTQFVDPCPKLATKWNFECKIFKYDVPMFCGKFLLKTSSCYEFV
PDPVKVLTKLGKKSIKDVQHLAEIYISLNDSNRALGNYMVVSKLSESVSDRYLYKGDSVHALCALWKHIKSFTALCTLFR
DENDKELNPAKVDWKKAQRAVSNFYDW
      904 - 911:      GvpgcGKS


>sp|P03589|1A_AMVLE  (1126 aa)
Replication protein 1a.  [Alfalfa mosaic virus (strain 425 / isolate Leiden)]
MNADAQSTDASLSMREPLSHASIQEMLRRVVEKQAADDTTAIGKVFSEAGRAYAQDALPSDKGEVLKISFSLDATQQNIL
RANFPGRRTVFSNSSSSSHCFAAAHRLLETDFVYRCFGNTVDSIIDLGGNFVSHMKVKRHNVHCCCPILDARDGARLTER
ILSLKSYVRKHPEIVGEADYCMDTFQKCSRRADYAFAIHSTSDLDVGELACSLDQKGVMKFICTMMVDADMLIHNEGEIP
NFNVRWEIDRKKDLIHFDFIDEPNLGYSHRFSLLKHYLTYNAVDLGHAAYRIERKQDFGGVMVIDLTYSLGFVPKMPHSN
GRSCAWYNRVKGQMVVHTVNEGYYHHSYQTAVRRKVLVDKKVLTRVTEVAFRQFRPNADAHSAIQSIATMLSSSTNHTII
GGVTLISGKPLSPDDYIPVATTIYYRVKKLYNAIPEMLSLLDKGERLSTDAVLKGSEGPMWYSGPTFLSALDKVNVPGDF
VAKALLSLPKRDLKSLFSRSATSHSERTPVRDESPIRCTDGVFYPIRMLLKCLGSDKFESVTITDPRSNTETTVDLYQSF
QKKIETVFSFILGKIDGPSPLISDPVYFQSLEDVYYAEWHQGNAIDASNYARTLLDDIRKQKEESLKAKAKEVEDAQKLN
RAILQVHAYLEAHPDGGKIEGLGLSSQFIAKIPELAIPTPKPLPEFEKNAETGEILRINPHSDAILEAIDYLKSTSANSI
ITLNKLGDHCQWTTKGLDVVWAGDDKRRAFIPKKNTWVGPTARSYPLAKYERAMSKDGYVTLRWDGEVLDANCVRSLSQY
EIVFVDQSCVFASAEAIIPSLEKALGLEAHFSVTIVDGVAGCGKTTNIKQIARSSGRDVDLILTSNRSSADELKETIDCS
PLTKLHYIRTCDSYLMSASAVKAQRLIFDECFLQHAGLVYAAATLAGCSEVIGFGDTEQIPFVSRNPSFVFRHHKLTGKV
ERKLITWRSPADATYCLEKYFYKNKKPVKTNSRVLRSIEVVPINSPVSVERNTNALYLCHTQAEKAVLKAQTHLKGCDNI
FTTHEAQGKTFDNVYFCRLTRTSTSLATGRDPINGPCNGLVALSRHKKTFKYFTIAHDSDDVIYNACRDAGNTDDSILAR
SYNHNF
      838 - 845:      GvagcGKT


>sp|Q9AT00|TGD3_ARATH  (345 aa)
Protein TRIGALACTOSYLDIACYLGLYCEROL 3, chloroplastic.  [Arabidopsis thaliana (Mouse-ear cress)]
MLSLSCSSSSSSLLPPSLHYHGSSSVQSIVVPRRSLISFRRKVSCCCIAPPQNLDNDATKFDSLTKSGGGMCKERGLEND
SDVLIECRDVYKSFGEKHILKGVSFKIRHGEAVGVIGPSGTGKSTILKIMAGLLAPDKGEVYIRGKKRAGLISDEEISGL
RIGLVFQSAALFDSLSVRENVGFLLYERSKMSENQISELVTQTLAAVGLKGVENRLPSELSGGMKKRVALARSLIFDTTK
EVIEPEVLLYDEPTAGLDPIASTVVEDLIRSVHMTDEDAVGKPGKIASYLVVTHQHSTIQRAVDRLLFLYEGKIVWQGMT
HEFTTSTNPIVQQFATGSLDGPIRY
      117 - 124:      GpsgtGKS
```

Can someone help me out with the right code?

Comment: I notice in both functions, `ZoekAccesieCode` and `ZoekOrganisme`, you only return the first value from `re.findall`. so you want at the end a single element dictionary ?

Comment: I think you want to return from these two functions, a list of strings not a single string ?...

Answer (score 1):

Going off your barely readable code.

```
def make_dict(a, b):
    return {a:b}
```

Comment: It pains me to think it, but this is likely the answer to the OP's question.

Comment: @sberry Yes, it was such a complex problem that I had to open Photoshop and draw the expected workflow before booting up Eclipse and painfully writing this complex super algorithm...!

Answer (score 0):

```
dictionary_name = {accesie:organisme}
```

Comment: I got this as an output: {'A': 'a', '0': 'd', 'Q': 'A', '9': 'r', 'T': 'b'} It needs to be something like: {'Q6GZX2':"Frog virus 3 (isolate Goorha)"}

Comment: accesie and organisme are not lists? If they're just strings, just create a dictionary.

Comment: They are strings I guess

Answer (score 0):

You can use `zip` or `itertools.izip_longest` like this

```
zip(accesie, organisme)
```

OR

```
itertools.izip_longest(accesie, organisme)
```

The former will only create as many pairs as the length of the longest input list.  The latter will give you potentially unmatched pairs if the lists are not of equal length.

Once you use either of the above, you can wrap it in a `dict()` to convert it.

```
>>> import itertools
>>> accesie = ['accesie1', 'accesie2', 'accesie3', 'accesie4']
>>> organisme = ['organisme1', 'organisme2', 'organisme3']
>>> dict(zip(accesie, organisme))
{'accesie3': 'organisme3', 'accesie2': 'organisme2', 'accesie1': 'organisme1'}
>>> dict(itertools.izip_longest(accesie, organisme))
{'accesie3': 'organisme3', 'accesie2': 'organisme2', 'accesie1': 'organisme1', 'accesie4': None}
```

It appears from reading other comments that you are dealing with single elements, not lists of elements.  As such you should refer to @TheLazyScripter's answer.  Simply create a dictionary with your key and value.

```
the_dict = {accesie: organisme}
```

If you are trying to add to the dict then it would be

```
the_dict[accesie] = organisme
```

Comment: Am I doing this right?       dict = {zip(accesie, organisme)}
      print(dict)

Answer (score 0):

This code has as a prerequisite that the values in accessie can be keys (they are strings or unicode) and that accessie and organisme are lists of the same length, otherwise you must use slicing to make them of the same length

```
dict(zip(accessie, organisme))
```